# promise "pending" in getusermedia error

Tags: javascript

I am trying get camera access from my mobile browser (UC browser) but it keeps on loading when I checked it in console it show video.readystate as 0 , and promise as pending I don't understand the error clearly what I found in google is that if its pending it will not play the camera, any one has idea on this

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(devices => {
      var videoDevices = [0,0];
      var videoDeviceIndex = 0;
      devices.forEach(function(device) {
        console.log("--- Index:"+videoDeviceIndex);
        console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
          " id = " + device.deviceId);
          console.log(device.kind);
         console.log(device.kind);
        if (device.kind == "videoinput") { 
            console.log(videoDevices[videoDeviceIndex] +":"+ device.deviceId);
            console.log(videoDevices +"--- val:"+videoDeviceIndex);
          videoDevices[videoDeviceIndex++] =  device.deviceId;  
          console.log(videoDevices +"--- after val:"+videoDeviceIndex);       
        }
      });


      var constraints =  {width: { min: 1024, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
      height: { min: 776, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
      deviceId: { exact: videoDevices[1]  } 
    };
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: constraints });

  }).then(function(stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
      video.play();
      requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    });
```

Comment: `promise as pending`  That's not an error, it just mean the Promise has not yet finished, you should be attaching a `then` somewhere here.

Comment: Add a `.catch(err => { console.error(err) })` to the end of the promise chain and check what error is reported.

Comment: @t.niese I added the code error catch but it doesn't show any error

Comment: @Keith that promise is pending from long time only for back camera not for front camera

Comment: *Where* do you log a promise that shows as pending?

Comment: @Bergi need to add after video.play(),    console.log(video.play()) it will display the promise status

Comment: Oh, [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) promise. Your title suggests you were having problems with the `getUserMedia` promise